The order of words in a sentence
On average we put adverbs after the first auxiliary verb. For instance "I have always been good". Sometimes, we want to emphasize something and we change the order. Could I ask you if  my mixed examples are acceptable?

I often haven't been good
I have often not been good
I haven't often been good
I haven't been often good


Negation changes things in tricky ways. If we're not careful, the negation can apply to the adverb instead of the verb.

"I never eat" —Eating is a thing I do not do.
"I never eat quickly" —I do eat; I just eat slowly.

In your examples about "being good," they all come out to roughly the same thing, but there are differences.

I often haven't been good —This one isn't very idiomatic, but it would seem to mean "Often—many times—I have not been good."
I have often not been good —This one is slightly more idiomatic, and would have the same meaning.
I haven't often been good —This one is the most idiomatic. The meaning is very slightly different: Maybe I have been good, but these times have not been often. Instead of "frequently bad" I've been "infrequently good." (But it really doesn't matter much, since "not being good" is taken to mean "being bad"; if we had a different scenario there might be more difference.)
I haven't been often good —This one is so unidiomatic it doesn't make sense very well.
You didn't ask about this, but another idiomatic option would be I haven't been good often. This would have the same meaning as #3.


I assume you meant to say that (4) is unidiomatic?

@KateBunting thanks for the catch

Okay. Do you find 1 and 2 idiomatic enough to use it once in a while or no?

@user203412 If I needed that specific meaning, I could imagine using either one. But it's more common to talk about "being bad" than about "not being good".

@AndyBonner not trying to act smart but I agree with you that 1 is possible yet are sure about 2 to me it seems to be really unusual?

Like I think that if I wrote 1 on a test it would be fine on the other hand I think that if I wrote 2 someone may take my points for that.

@KateBunting what do you think?

@user203412 Honestly, I find it hard to imagine ever talking about "not being good," especially as if there were countable instances of it. I think it's just that "not being" is hard to conceptualize as an action. It's a lot easier to say "I've been bad," or "I've been good," then "I haven't been ___." For this reason both 1 and 2 are problematic.

It might be a different example I just find it strange putting an advetb between an auxiliary verb and not

For instance "I have always not done it

As usual, context is everything. I agree with Andy that it would be much more natural to talk about 'being bad' or 'behaving badly', but in a conversation where someone had spoken of 'not being good' on a particular occasion, I can imagine someone else confessing "I have often 'not been good'".
